# cstdint not compiling in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

cstdint is not compiling for me in xcode and giving me errors like:

No member named 'uint8_t' in the global namespace
etc.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue? To clarify, my header search paths do not touch /usr/local/include/ folder. I am using /usr/local/Cellar/ for my header search path.

Edit: Attached images of build settings
[image]

[image]

Comment: With what code? You're probably missing an `#include`.

Comment: Why are you using `Cellar` with Xcode? That's not where Xcode will find its own headers.

Comment: I meant user header search paths. I saw a post where using /usr/local/include causes issues. I am using cellar to locate brew installed dependencies such as eigen, etc.

Comment: Does using recursive search cause issues? I am using recursive search to find headers but that seems to cause the compile errors above. If I don't use it then the files aren't found.

Comment: A) You haven't shown any code so we can try and reproduce the problem. B) XCode comes with headers specific to that version of `clang` used. They cannot be arbitrarily replaced. C) You should try this without any of your unusual alterations in place.

Comment: I haven't shown any code because this is a large project. It has also been successfully compiled with cmake. I just wanted to port it to xcode and let xcode handle the builds. I'll take a look at the clang versions.

Comment: When using Xcode, use the Xcode headers as well. These are not interchangeable.

Comment: I added screenshots of the build settings if it makes the situation more clear in any way. What exactly do you mean by xcode headers?

Comment: Don't change those defaults unless you know exactly what you're doing and have a compelling reason to do it. Delete that override.

Comment: If I don't change the defaults how do I find brew installed libraries? I think that should have been my first question.

Comment: That's making a *lot* more sense. You add that on, you don't replace it. Xcode allows you to edit that and "+" a new entry, which is what you want. Normally you layer on *additional* search paths. You never replace those that are already there. They are there for a reason.

Comment: Actually I don't think I replaced anything. I did just add onto what was originally there. Is there a default it is supposed to search?

Comment: It looks like you've stomped the original search path and replaced it with your own. You need to add on, not replace.

Comment: I  may be completely off base here, so try compiling a trivial program with that `uint8_t` reference in it and see what comes up.

Comment: I removed the header searches and created a trivial program which compiled. But, if I don't remove the header searches they don't compile

Comment: I think I have a good idea of what is causing the error. I believe that maybe calling /usr/local/Cellar recursively is finding other versions of cstdint that may not be compatible. Is there a workaround for this. Should I just call each dependency very specifically?

Comment: I'd include *exactly* the header paths you need. Normally this means very specific locations based on what was installed.